# Outlook/VBA: Getting the Current View's Start and End Date

Tags: vba, outlook

I've programmed VBA for various Office applications, but I'm new to Outlook, so I'm still learning the various Outlook objects.

In the Outlook calendar view, I'm either in a "Day", "Work Week", "Week", "Month", or "Schedule View" arrangement. I can change between these however I want to see my events. Today being November 29, 2016, displayed above my calendar (Outlook 2016) I see:

- **Day**: "November 29, 2016"
- **Work Week**: "November 28 - December 2, 2016"
- **Week**: "November 26 - December 2, 2016"
- etc...

This is obviously a date range for my current *view* (probably the incorrect term).

How do I reference the beginning and/or end dates of this *view* in VBA? I want to clarify that I do *NOT* want the beginning and end dates of a *selection* (which is what I'm finding online), but of the actual view--what I'm seeing at the moment on my Outlook client application.

Thanks in advance for your time and assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the `CalendarView.DisplayDates` property.  This is an array containing each date displayed.  Get the first and last value in the array.  See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff864304.aspx).

Code reproduced and altered for clarity below:

```
Sub DisplayDayRange()

 Dim objView As CalendarView
 Dim varArray As Variant
 Dim beginDate As Date
 Dim endDate As Date

    ' Check if the current view is a calendar view.

    If Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentView.ViewType = olCalendarView Then       

        ' Obtain a CalendarView object reference for the     
        ' current calendar view.

        Set objView = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentView

        ' Obtain the DisplayedDates value, a string  
        ' array of dates representing the dates displayed           
        ' in the calendar view.

        varArray = objView.DisplayedDates

        ' If the example obtained a valid array, display  
        ' a dialog box with a summary of its contents.

        If IsArray(varArray) Then

            beginDate = varArray(LBound(varArray))
            endDate = varArray(UBound(varArray))
            MsgBox "There are " & (UBound(varArray) - LBound(varArray)) + 1 & " days displayed, from " & beginDate & " to " & endDate  
        End If     
    End If

 End Sub
```